# Remove links to urls with certain suffix PHP wildcard

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, wildcard

Need to copy and paste large body of text and it's filled with

`<a href="default.asp?contentID=XXX">xxx</a>`

Looking for a way to remove all links with the path "deafult.asp?.........."

I am using PHP wordpress to be exact.

....Let me clarify I want to remove the links that looks like this

`<a href="default.asp?contentID=123">example text</a>`

while preserving the "example text" I am trying to remove the link and leave the text. so remove the `<a>` tag and everything inside the tag while leaving the "example text". However I don't want to remove every `<a>` tag on my page. Just the links reffuring to `deafult.asp?contentID=somenumber`.

Comment: @matthew i have tried the preg_replace as suggested by @ msgmash.com but no luck so far. I have also tried some regexp lines but im not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preg_replace is your friend. For example, the following achieves what you want.

```
$str = "hello <a href='default.asp?contentID=123'>example text</a> bye <a href='/check/default.asp?contentID=456'>example text 2</a>";

$str2 = preg_replace("/<a.*?default.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/","$1",$str);
```

I'm sure someone can suggest a better regexp, but it gets the job done.

Comment: For this i will need to manually input all the link variations and there is a bunch of numbers at the end that are all different. 

is there a way it will remove the link if it finds the word default in it?

Comment: doesnt work for me... maybe wordpress is doing something funky =/

Comment: it works using the example urls you provided, so perhaps the URLs you are trying to change are different to your examples

Comment: @msgmash.com Here are some URLs Ive pulled from the site. `default.asp?contentID=314` `default.asp?contentID=312` `default.asp?contentID=315` `default.asp?contentID=317` they are all the same except the last 3 digits.